# Error of “plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded” in DolphinDB

Tags: mysql, plugins, dolphindb

I added a configuration parameter preloadModules=plugins::mysql in the configuration file dolphindb.cfg. The following error is reported:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, `caching_sha2_password` is the default authentication plugin rather than `mysql_native_password`. If the error “plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded” is reported in DolphinDB, you can use a lower-version MySQL plugin.

You can connect in the following steps:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p123456 //username root, password 123456
use mysql;
```

Specify the authentication plugin locally:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456'; //123456是密码
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Or specify the authentication plugin remotely:

```
ALTER USER root@‘%‘ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456'; //123456是密码
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Comment: What to do if MySQL auth policy can't be changed?